# How do I trigger useEffect if the dependency was set, but the value of the dependency stayed the same?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

How do I trigger useEffect if the dependency was set, but the value of the dependency stayed the same? Here's an example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [dependency, setDependency] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Triggered!");
    }, [dependency]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div onMouseDown={() => setDependency(1)}>
                set dependency to 1
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Right now when I set dependency to 1 for the first time, it triggers, but if I do this for the second time and further, it doesn't trigger.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Because you are submitting the same value. state still the same useEffect won't trigger.

Suggestion :

```
<div onMouseDown={() => setDependency(dependency+1)}>
     set dependency to 1
/div>
```

Answer (score -1):

From the second time onwards your state will be the same i.e `1`. So useEffect won't be called. Read more about [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to clear your concepts.

If you want to call on each mouseDown event then make sure you're updating the state value which is not the same as the current value.

For that, one solution is you can add keep updating your state by adding fixed integer value. Like shown below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
    const [dependency, setDependency] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Triggered!");
    }, [dependency]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div onMouseDown={() => setDependency(1 + **N**)}> // N can be any static int value. 
                set dependency to 1 + N
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```